# Missing required parameter for [Route: admin.clues.update] [URI: admin/clues/{game}/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

When I am clicking on the edit button I am getting this error.

> Missing required parameter for [Route: admin.clues.update]
> [URI: admin/clues/{game}/{id}] [Missing parameter: id] here is the edit button

```
 <button class="btn btn_action actionButton" style="background-color: #66a4e4;">
 <a href="{{ route('admin.clues.edit', ['game' => $game->slug, 'id' => $clue->id]) }}">
 <i class="fa fa-pencil icon_span" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
 </button>
```

Web route:

```
Route::get('/{id}/edit', [ClueController::class, 'edit'])->name('admin.clues.edit');
Route::patch('/{id}', [ClueController::class, 'update'])->name('admin.clues.update');
```

Form action of edit page:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.clues.update', ['game' => $game, 'id' => $clue->id]) }}"
    id="clue-edit-form"
    method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
```

Controller:

```
public function edit($game, Clue $clue)
{
    $game = Game::where('slug', $game)->first();
    return view('admin.clues.edit', ['game' => $game, 'clue' => $clue]);
}

/**
 * Update clue
 */
public function update(Request $request )
{
    return redirect()->route('admin.clues');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not doing any bindings in the [RouteServiceProvider](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic), you may need to change the signature of the edit function as [implicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#implicit-binding) of the resource Clue would not be effective.

```
public function edit($game, $id)
{
    $game = Game::where('slug', $game)->first();

    $clue = Clue::find($id);

    return view('admin.clues.edit', ['game' => $game, 'clue' => $clue]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to a missing parameter in the route for the "edit" button. In your route definition, you have specified the `{id}` parameter, but in your button link, you are passing the id parameter. The names need to match for Laravel to resolve the correct route.

your code should look something like this :

```
<button class="btn btn_action actionButton" style="background-color: #66a4e4;">
    <a href="{{ route('admin.clues.edit', ['id' => $clue->id]) }}">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil icon_span" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
</button>
```